# How to use a Loop within a Function that accepts two parameters, an Array and a Number

Tags: arrays, function, loops, parameters

I'm trying to solve the problem below using a for loop.

Write a function that adds an element to the end of an array.

However, the element should only be added if it is not already in the array.

For example:

`Add([1, 2], 3)` should return `[1, 2, 3]`  and `add([1, 2], 2)` should return `[1, 2]`.

Here is my attempt at it:  Any help is appreciated.

```
 function add(arr, num) {

    var newArr = arr.slice();

    for (i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; i++)

     if (arr[i] !== num)
        {
         return newArr.push(num);

        }

     else {
            return arr;
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
function add (arr, num) {    
    for (i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == num) 
            return arr;
    } 
    return arr.push(num);
}
```

Test:

```
arr = [6, 10, 12, 25]

add(arr,101)

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkNum (arr, num) {    
    for (i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i] == num) 
            return arr;
    } 
    return arr.push(num);
}
```

to test it:

```
arr=[1,2,3]
checkNum(arr,3)
arr.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I appreciate it.  I just tried to console.log(add([6, 10, 12, 25], 100))  and the answer i get is 5 not [6, 10, 12, 25, 100].  I'm not sure what I'm missing as i was getting a similar result when i ran my original code.

Comment: glad i could help you.can you plz validate the answer?

Comment: I'm not getting the correct answer when I run your code... For example:  console.log(checkNum([1, 2], 3)) gives me a result of 3, not [1, 2, 3].  Thank you.

Comment: i think you are testing wrong cause it work fine for me.did you use      
  arr.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
  });

Comment: function checkNum (arr, num) {

  for (i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] == num) 
      return arr;
  } 
  return arr.push(num);
}
arr=[6, 10, 12, 25, 100]
checkNum(arr,100)
arr.forEach(function(entry) {
  console.log(entry);
});
this printed: 6
                   10
                   12
                   25
                   100

Comment: Yes, thank you. I got this to work but need the result to be returned in an array.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, convert the **inputted numbers** for possibilities of more than one input by using a **rest parameter [...num]** and store it in a variable of **searchNum**.
2. Then loop through the **searchNum** or inputted number(s) using **map**
3. Then an **optional sorting** of the array, but it's best practice to sort except otherwise, cause the inputted number(s) could come in, in no particular order
4. Afterward we filter the inputted number(s) to check if our array by indexing already has an index number of our inputted number(s) if it doesn't(-1), then we want to push into the array the current item (inputted number). Else, just return our array cause our index value will change to true (1) and won't remain as false (-1).
5. Keep looping until all inputted numbers return true.

```
    let add = (arr, ...num) => {
        let searchNum = [...num]
        searchNum.map(item => item)
        .sort((a, b) => a - b)
        .filter(item => {
            if (arr.indexOf(item) === -1) {
                arr.push(item)
            } else {
                return arr
            }
        })
        return arr
    }
    let addResult = add([1, 2],3,9,4,3,5) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9]
    console.log(addResult)
```